# Haskell arrows: insert value to a list

Tags: haskell, hxt

I am learning haskell arrows in case of parsing simple html page.
The task is to download site of base region `baseRegion = Region "Yekaterinburg" "http://example.com/r/ekb"`, parse links to another regions (via hxt):

```
regions :: ArrowXml cat => cat a (NTree XNode) -> cat a Region
regions tree =
  tree >>> multi (hasName "a" >>> hasAttrValue "class" (== ".regionlink")) >>>
    proc x -> do
      rname <- getText <<< getChildren -< x
      rurl <- getAttrValue "href" -< x
      returnA -< Region rname rurl
```

and append a base region to the result:

```
allRegions :: ArrowXml cat => cat a (NTree XNode) -> cat a Region
```

1. How to write `allRegions`? Or, better, where should I dig to write it?
2. Another question is how to not only append `regions`'s result but insert `baseRegion` to some particular place of regions list (for example after the second element or after an element whose name is starting with 'E')?

Comment: Are you looking at something like: `regions (getXMLFromRegion region)` being successively called starting from `baseRegion`? So that you can keep appending the results in a flat list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the combinator you are looking for is [`(>>.)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.4/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html#v%3a-62--62--46-) in the [`ArrowList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.4/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html) type-class. It allows you to apply any list function on the arrow. E.g. prepending an element to the front of the arrow would be.

```
regions tree >>. (baseRegion:)
```

So as for your second question, you can write an utility function to insert the region in the list to the correct spot e.g. something with a signature like

```
insertRegion :: Region -> [Region] -> [Region]
```

and then you can use it on the arrow

```
regions tree >>. insertRegion baseRegion
```

Btw I would personally remove the tree parameter from your `regions` function and just use explicit arrow chaining so the above becomes.

```
tree >>> regions >>. insertRegion baseRegion
```